# My settings for the font size or the size of the text fields are ignored

Tags: html, css

I make a website where the temperature and humidity are stored. I read out these values from a sensor. I'm currently working on the basic design of the website, but I can't get any further. One of my buttons slipped down and so I tried to make the textareas smaller. When that didn't work, I tried to reduce the font size of the elements. Unfortunately that didn't work either. I tried that in CSS and HTML code.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33.33% 33.3% 33.3%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  text-align: center;
}

.cbtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#e6 {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
}

#e7 {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
}

#e8 {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 9 / 10;
}

#h1Title {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 43px;
}

#pTemperature {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#pHumidity {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#OutputTemp {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#OutputHumi {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#buttonStart {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
}

#buttonStop {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
}

#pExplemation1 {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 5 / 6;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#TempGreenMin {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 6 / 7;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#pAnd1 {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 6 / 7;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#TempGreenMax {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 6 / 7;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#pExplemation2 {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 7 / 8;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#HumiGreenMin {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 8 / 9;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#pAnd2 {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 8 / 9;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#HumiGreenMax {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 8 / 9;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#buttonSave {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 9 / 10;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 id="h1Title" font="43px">Temperature und humidity</h1>
  <p id="pTemperature " font="25px">Temperature </p>
  <p id="pHumidity" font="25px">humidity</p>
  <p id="OutputTemp" font="25px">--°C</p>
  <p id="OutputHumi" font="25px">--%</p>
  <span class="cbtn" id="e6" font="25px"><button id="buttonStart">Start</button></span>
  <span class="cbtn" id="e7" font="25px"><button id="buttonStop">Stop</button></span>
  <p id="pExplemation1" font="25px">Green temperatures Range: between</p>
  <textarea id="TempGreenMin" font="25px"></textarea>
  <p id="pAnd1" font="25px">and</p>
  <textarea id="TempGreenMax" font="25px"></textarea>
  <p id="pExplemation2" font="25px">Gree humidity range: between</p>
  <textarea id="LumiGreenMin" font="25px"></textarea>
  <p id="pAnd2" font="25px">and</p>
  <textarea id="HumiGreenMax" font="25px"></textarea>
  <span class="cbtn" id="e8" font="25px"><button id="buttonSave">Save</button></span>
</div>
```

Comment: What button are you trying to make the font size smaller for? All of them?

Comment: Yes, all of them. Also the Textarea and <p>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I happened to get another variant by another post who misunderstood my question. I tried it, and it worked...
I changed font="25px" to style="font-size:25px".
Link to the page: [HTML-Styles](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_styles.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Your `font-size` declaration is redundant. You’re declaring inline as well as in your css. I’m guessing you’re changing one and the other is overriding. There is no need to have `font` declared inline in your HTML, just remove it and declare it in your css, then you are free to choose whatever value you’d like without interference.

```
<span class="cbtn" id="e7">...</span>

#e7 { 
   font-size:25px; // or whatever value you’d like
}
```

Furthermore, as it’s a bit unclear what you’re asking, if you want to change the font of the `button` only, you’ll need to target that `button`, not just its container, like so:

```
.buttonStart {
   font-size:25px;
}
```

Also, it’s not really great practice to have a `button` inside a `span`. Whatever you’re trying to achieve by laying it out that way, there is a better way to do it.

Comment: I know I have the font-size in both places. That was just to show where I tried. That because of the chip is another story. I have a 3*9 grid and couldn't center the buttons in their fields. I finally managed to do it with chips. Link to the post in another forum. [Link](https://www.html.de/threads/meine-einstellungen-zur-schriftgroesse-werden-ignoriert-bzw-groesse-der-textfelder.59321/) Attention is in German.

Comment: Not chip. span.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to change the font size instead of HTML attributes. Recommend you to create a CSS class to do font styling and call it whenever needed.

```
.fsize { font-size: 50px;}
```

or based on the HTML tag id

```
#pTemperature { font-size: 50px;}
```

Also, this will help you to change your page appearance easily.